# What can be the regex to find comments in line "10 println "Testing if then" //Test Comment

Tags: java, regex, comments, lexer

For the line,

```
10  println "Testing Comment" //Test Comment
```

What can be the regex to find "//Test Comment" as a whole string. I want to use this for tokenization as i am creating a lexer in java.

Code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String[] p = new String[5];
    p[0] = "(?<Reserved>\\bPRINTLN\\b)"; //RESERVED WORDS 
    p[1] = "(?<Comments> //.*)";
    p[2] = "(?<Constants>[0-9]+)"; //Constants eg: 21 54 14215
    p[3] = "(?<Special>[\\[\\]/.$*\\-+=><#()%,!|&{}])"; //SPECIAL CHAR Eg:-+*/ etc
    p[4] = "(?<Identifiers>\\w+)"; //Identifiers eg: circum radius


    for (String s: p) {
        sb.append(String.format("|(%s)", s)); 
    } //for ends here

    Pattern tp = Pattern.compile(new String(sb.substring(1))); // adding the patterns one after another separated by |

    Matcher m = tp.matcher(line);
```

I have tried using //.* but its not matching that the comments.
Using find method from matcher, i am tokenizing based on named capturing group.

Comment: Tried "//.* "   , but no luck

Comment: Have a look at  https://regex101.com/  and try   \/\/.*

Comment: giving compilation error "Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )" for "\/\/.*"

Comment: Updated additional code

Comment: so for java you will need to escapre your escapres, so `\\/\\/.*`

Comment: @ScaryWombat - This works, i had add an extra \ to both. i.e \\/\\/.*. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(?=\/\/)[\s\S]+
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/1IESlB/1

Answer (score 2):

You can try [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/P6qGJB/1):

```
\/\/.*
```

- `\/\/` matches `//` starting the comment
- `.*` matches any amount of character following the `//`, except line terminators

Your problem must be that you used `//` instead of `\/\/`. `/` is a meta character and has be escaped with a backslash. NExt time I would suggest you to use [regex101](http://regex101.com) before asking, simple errors will be highlighted and you can test it quickly.

Comment: Worked for me when i added 2 \. i.e \\/\\.*. Thanks. I will definitively use the link you provided.